# How to handle initials at the end of a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I came across this sentence:

"They are only distributed in the U.S. Payment occurs in a similar fashion to mag-stripe, without a PIN and often in off-line mode..."

On reading the first time, I got confused by "U.S. Payment." It seemed to be the name of an organization, but the subsequent words were out of place. So I re-read and realized that "Payment" was the start of a new sentence.

Is there a way to disambiguate the period at the end of "U.S." so it is immediately obvious that the sentence has ended, or do we have to rely on context ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several things you can do here:

> "The U.S. is the only place they are distributed. Payment occurs in a similar fashion to mag-stripe, without a PIN and often in off-line mode..."
>
> "They are only distributed in the U.S.; payment occurs in a similar fashion to mag-stripe, without a PIN and often in off-line mode..."
>
> "They are only distributed in the US. Payment occurs in a similar fashion to mag-stripe, without a PIN and often in off-line mode..."
>
> "They are only distributed in the United States. Payment occurs in a similar fashion to mag-stripe, without a PIN and often in off-line mode..."

Using or omitting periods in the abbreviation of state and country names will be determined by the style guide you use. (*The Chicago Manual of Style* recommends not using periods.)

But there's often no problem with using a semicolon, and you can always choose to spell out the long name.

Comment: "you can always choose to spell out the long name."  Yes.